# Monthly data in Google Trends

Tags: data-request, extracting, trends

After searching for a word in google trends I can only get access to weekly data .csv files. How can I easily get access to monthly data ? I feel like I just missed a button or something.

I've found this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332243/trying-to-download-google-trends-data-but-date-parameter-is-ignored),  which seems to work according to commentaries, but don't really know how to handle all this code (and a bit skeptical about hardcoding my google Ids...).

Answer (score 1):

*note: this answer is based on [another answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4247/1511), with some modifications for your question.*

Google Trends doesn't have an API, but you can follow instructions from [this great blog post](http://techslides.com/hacking-the-google-trends-api) to hack it. The raw data is in JSON form here:

```
http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/
```

and using this [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) command you can change date and region:

```
curl --data "ajax=1&geo=US&date=201310" http://www.google.com/trends/topcharts/category
```

This request would give you Google trends from the US in October 2013.

Output:

- Unformatted JSON file for the above curl request - [LINK](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uFVj2TYU).
- Same data in a JSON formatted web tool - [LINK](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/1cbe4f).

If you aren't comfortable programming a tool to parse this JSON output, you can use something like [OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/index.html) as a front-end. With this kind of tool, I think you can convert to CSV. There are also some webtools to convert JSON to CSV ([example](http://konklone.io/json/)). Note that the JSON format is for data-interchange and requires understanding the structure for proper transfer to a tabular format (like CSV). Data is stored as key/value and the values can be dictionaries, lists, or any other data-type.